# "Covariance" of the System.Nullable<> struct

Tags: c#, nullable, covariance

When we have two structs, and one is implicitly convertible to the other, then it seems like the `System.Nullable<>` versions of the two are also implicitly convertible. Like, if struct `A` has an implicit conversion to struct `B`, then `A?` converts to `B?` as well.

Here is an example:

```
struct MyNumber
{
  public readonly int Inner;

  public MyNumber(int i)
  {
    Inner = i;
  }

  public static implicit operator int(MyNumber n)
  {
    return n.Inner;
  }
}
```

Inside some method:

```
MyNumber? nmn = new MyNumber(42);
int? covariantMagic = nmn; // works!
```

In the C# Language Specification Version 4.0 we read that a conversion like this shall exist for "the predefined implicit identity and numeric conversions".

But **is it safe to assume** that it will also work for user-defined implicit conversions?

(This question might be related to this bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/642227/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But is it safe to assume that it will also work for user-defined implicit conversions?

Yes. From section 6.4.2 of the C# 4 spec:

> Given a user-defined conversion operator that convers from a non-nullable value type `S` to a non-nullable value type `T`, a *lifted conversion operator* exists that converts from `S?` to `T?`. This lifted conversion operator performs an unwrapping from `S?` to `S` followed by the user-defined conversion from `S` to `T`, followed by a wrapping from `T` to `T?`, except that a null-valued `S?` converts directly to a null-valued `T?`.
>
> A lifted conversion operator has the same implicit or explicit classification as its underlying user-defined conversion operator. The term "user-defined conversion" applies to the use of both user-defined and lifted conversion operators.

Comment: Do you even have time to look these quotes up or do you just type em by hand?

Comment: @Blindy: Both! I have a hard copy of the spec on my desk, and I copied this section out by typing... hence any typos!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Hey, it just makes me happy that other people are reading the spec at all :)